# HSV mask within two ranges

Tags: python, opencv, hsv

Here's my issue:

I need to isolate the blue curve from the following image :

[image]

The curve can be anywhere in the image, so I implemented a pattern recognition which works just fine, giving me the following box:

[image]

Now, what I'm trying to do is extract the curve itself. The curve can be of whatever color, so I thought I'd extract the dominants color in the picture and apply a HSV mask corresponding to those.
I've managed to do so and recover the colors of the curve.
These are, in BGR : [68, 240, 86] and [160, 81, 76]

Now my issue is finding the HSV value corresponding in order to apply the mask. All the things I've tried ended up in a completely black result.

Here's my current code for the mask:

```
low = np.uint8([[llow]])
high = np.uint8([[lhigh]])

hsv_low = cv2.cvtColor(low, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    
hsv_high = cv2.cvtColor(high, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

print(hsv_low, hsv_high)

mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, hsv_low, hsv_high)

output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask1)

show("hsv", output)
wait()
```

with:

```
llow = [68, 240, 86] 
lhigh = [160, 81, 76]
```

I also believe the HSV value obtained are kind of weird, with
hsv_low ending up being [86, 240, 68] and hsv_high [76, 81, 160], so I don't know which one should be the lower range or the high one. (I've tried to switch them but no changes occured)
Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: when posting pictures, it's a very good idea to use PNG because it's lossless.

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe with masks

```
lower_blue = np.array([60, 40, 40])
upper_blue = np.array([130, 255, 255])
```

They are already in HSV color colorspace and I got picture looking like this. Now you would only need to fill holes from the green scale.

[image]

Comment: Hey, Thanks for taking the time to answer, I've also managed to achieve this by handling the range by hand, but I'd really like to automate it thanks to the range of color I've retrieved in the previous step...

Comment: you don't need to fill those gaps because in the original, the whole curve has the same color. he posted a JPEG picture, which messes with color information.